# How to apply some style to p tag come after specific h tag except other h tags in PDF kit

Tags: css, flask, pdfkit, python-pdfkit

I would like to set margin-left:1em to p tag shown after h1
and also after h2: 2em, after h3: 3em, after h4: 4em.

How can I do?

Here is my code.

```css
    h1~p {margin-left: 1em}
    h2~p {margin-left: 2em}
    h3~p {margin-left: 3em}
```

```html
<h1>chapter1</h1>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<h2>section1-1</h2>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<h3>1-1-1</h3>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<h1>chapter2</h1>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<h2>section2-1</h2>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<h3>2-1-1</h3>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<p>some paragraph</p>
<p>some paragraph</p>
```

I would like to set 1em on p between `<h1>chapter2</h1>` and `<h2>section2-1</h2>` but it is 3em.
How can I implement this without adding html tag?

---

Add 2019/07/22

The HTML data is sent from web form written in Markdown and convert to html by flask (python framework) markdown library.

Then I would like to output PDF file marked up by css with PDFKit.

Comment: this code is fixed or can change?

Comment: @Temani Afif If possible, I do not want to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about having a fixed number of `p` tags after the headers, you can use the immediate CSS selector `+`. Assuming that there will be not more than 3 paragraphs, you can do as

```
h1 + p {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

h1 + p + p {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

h1 + p + p + p {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

Fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/saksham_malhotra/afz6dsqu/

Comment: It is not clear how many paragraphs are there because the data is sent from web form.

Comment: I am using PDFKit to markup by css and convert to PDF file. Dose this information affect your answer?

Comment: @user4565857 I'm afraid but you will have to do it this way itself and add as many rules as you can. I'll definitely update the answer if I find any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use adjacent sibling combinator to achieve this.

```
h1+p {margin-left: 1em}
h1+p+p{margin-left: 1em}
h1+p+p+p{margin-left: 1em}

h2+p{margin-left: 2em}
h2+p+p{margin-left: 2em}
h2+p+p+p{margin-left: 2em}

h3+p{margin-left: 3em}
h3+p+p{margin-left: 3em}
h3+p+p+p{margin-left: 3em}
```

But as you can see the code becomes very messy and overwhelming. So I would recommend you to use a div to enclose the different set of paragraphs and give them a class name and style them separately. This will drastically improve both the readability and efficiency of the code.

Comment: I am using PDFKit to markup by css and convert to PDF file. Dose this information affect your answer?

Answer (score -1):

Try this, just add a `<div>` container.

```css
h1~div {margin-left: 1em}
h2~div {margin-left: 2em}
h3~div {margin-left: 3em}

h1 + div{
  color:red;
}
h2 + div{
  color:blue;
}
h3 + div{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<h1>chapter1</h1>
<div>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
</div>
<h2>section1-1</h2>
<div>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
</div>
<h3>1-1-1</h3>
<div>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
</div>
<h1>chapter2</h1>
<div>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
</div>
<h2>section2-1</h2>
<div>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
</div>
<h3>2-1-1</h3>
<div>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
  <p>some paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: from the question : **How can I implement this without adding html tag?**

Comment: I think there is not a way to do this without adding html tags

Comment: I am using PDFKit to markup by css and convert to PDF file. Dose this information affect your answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can try add a class or an id to h-tag needed and then use selesctors like
h1#id p

Comment: I am using PDFKit to markup by css and convert to PDF file. Dose this information affect your answer?

Comment: None of that, it appeals to the inner css syntax which can be used anywhere in terms of writing css code